# How to simulate atom_to_term(+Atom, -Term, -Bindings) of SWI-Prolog in SICStus Prolog?

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog

I am using SICStus Prolog to write a Dali agent and I need to convert an atom to a term but I can't use `atom_to_term` which is built in in SWI-Prolog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`library(codesio)`](http://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dcodesio.html):

```
| ?- use_module(library(codesio)).
yes
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,codes).
true.
| ?- read_from_codes("a(X,Y).",T).     

T = a(_A,_B) ? yes
| ?- read_term_from_codes("a(X,Y).",T,[variable_names(VN_list)]).
T = a(_A,_B),
VN_list = ['X'=_A,'Y'=_B] ?
```

In addition to that, you need `atom_codes/2` which is ISO.

For more complex operations, you can open a stream with `open_codes_stream/2`. Which needs to be closed with `close/1`.

Comment: can you please take a look at what I'm trying to do and help achieve it as explained in the edited question?

Comment: @user3025515: Write a new question for this. You asked a different question. I will revert what you added, after you added the question.