# Split integer from atom in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to split an integer from an atom. Any ideas how I could do that?

Sample query:

```
?- split_int('nc(4)', N).      % given:    the atom 'nc(4)'
N = 4.                         % expected: the integer  4
```

Comment: `?- atom_to_term('nc(4)', nc(N), []).` yields: **N = 4**.

Comment: @Giththan without quotes like `nc(4)` you can use   `split_int(Fact,N) :- arg(1,Fact,N).`

Comment: @mat `atom_to_term/3` is it available in SICStus-prolog,if not is there other alternative ?

Comment: Check it out: SICStus-based [emulation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20165720/1613573)!

Comment: @mat thx,what I found in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165720/how-to-simulate-atom-to-termatom-term-bindings-of-swi-prolog-in-sicstus-p)  is for the double_quotes , not for **'    '**  like  `'foo'` --> foo

Comment: @mat Thank you for your answers and comments.

Comment: @Ans Piter  Thank you for your answer,Its also useful.

Answer (score 0):

In SWI Prolog, you should be able to say something like

```
?- term_to_atom( nc(N) , 'nc(4)' ).
N = 4.
```

and get what you want. In Sicstus, it looks like you need to use [`library(codesio)`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dcodesio.html). That should let you say something like this:

```
atom_to_term( A , T ) :-
  atom_codes( A , Cs ) ,
  read_from_codes( Cs , T )
  .
```

Though you'll have to ensure your atom is terminated by a period/full stop. `'nc(4)'` won't work, but `'nc(4).'` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote the below program by using SWI prolog 6,

```
atom_chars => convert to char list,
and process the char list to get the number characters
and use atom_chars/2, atom_number/2 to change it back to number
```

https://github.com/neojou/prolog/blob/master/examples/split_int.pl

?- split_int('nc(4)', N).
N = 4.

?- split_int('nc(1234)', N).
N = 1234.